# What is the encoding used in encode function with escape in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a bytea stored in the database , I'm trying to convert it to string via the encode function and it works :

```
select encode(blobvalue,'escape') from myTable ;
```

However the following is failing :

```
select convert_from(blobvalue,'UTF8') from myTable ;

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xac
```

my server encoding is UTF8:

```
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
 server_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

any explanation why the encode is working but the convert_from not ? isn't the encoding used in encode with escape same as server encoding ?

Comment: Well apparently the binary data in your `bytea` column is not UTF-8 encoded. The real question is why you store strings in a `bytea` column, not a `text`  column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's an object stored in the database ( serializable object). but what is the encoding used in encode ? how did it use the right encoding which is not UTF-8 ?

Comment: `encode()` does not do character encoding. It's used to convert binary value to hex, or base64 (e.g. to send an image as a string). but if that is "an object", then how can that be converted to a string?

Comment: I still can see the class names ( ArrayList ... ) in the encode with escape , while with encode hex/base64 it's not showing. so there is some kind of encoding done.

Comment: How can a Java object be de-serialized to a String? I would expect that you need to load the binary data, then create a Java object from that class data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encode()` will only convert ASCII bytes to characters. Everything else will be an escaped octal value:

```
SELECT encode('\x4142AC43', 'escape');

 encode  
═════════
 AB\254C
(1 row)
```

Here, the byte 0xAC is not an ASCII character and is rendered as `\254`.

`convert_from()`, on the other hand, considers the `bytea` as a string in a certain encoding and will fail if it finds bytes that are not correct:

```
SELECT convert_from('\x4142AC43', 'UTF8');
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xac
```

So you have to figure out in which encoding your `bytea` value actually is.